# How to specy ECS service name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

It seems like taskDefiinition is used for service name. I currently have taskDefinition for old names. Does it mean that I need to deregister this definitions first? This should be automated via ecs-cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--project-name` in ecs cli service up works

> Specifies the project name to use. If the COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME
>   environment variable is set when ecs-cli compose is run, then the
>   project name is set to the value of that environment variable.
>
> Type: String
>
> Default: The current directory name.
>
> Required: No

[source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose.html)